# How to use Sitemappath control to add breadcrumbs in Master Page of a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

I am trying to add breadcrumbs on my web pages for easy navigation. For this I am using SiteMapPath Control of Asp.Net and along with this I have also made a breadcrumb.Sitemap file which list all the pages. But While implementing the sitemappath in my master page, I am getting a generic error. I am not able to understand why is this happening?
This is the basic structure of my aspx page-

```
<div id="menu-pt">
<div class="hm"><a href="Page1.aspx" class="active">Home</a></div>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="nav" name="nav">
                <li><a href="Page2.aspx">Page2</a></li>
                <div class="saparation"></div>
                <li><a href="Page3.aspx">Page3</a></li>
                <div class="saparation"></div>
             <li> <a href="Page4.aspx">Page4</a></li>
            <div class="saparation"></div>
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
            <div id ="Ul2" runat="server">
                <ul id="sub-nav" >
                <li><a href="Page5.aspx">Page5</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page6.aspx">Page6</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page7.aspx">Page7</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page8.aspx">Page8</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
             <div id ="Ul1" runat="server">
             <ul id="sub-nav" >

                <li><a href="Page9.aspx">Page9</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page10.aspx">Page10</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page11.aspx">Page11</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page12.aspx">Page12</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page13.aspx">Page13</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
                </li>          
           </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Page5,6,7,8.aspx pages is for all users. And

Page9,10,11,12,13.aspx pages are for logged in user.
And My breadcrumb.sitemap file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="Page1.aspx" title="Home"  description="Page1">
        <siteMapNode url="Page2.aspx" title="Page2"  description="Page2" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page3.aspx" title="Page3"  description="Page3" />
      <siteMapNode url="Page4.aspx" title="Page4"  description="Page4" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Pages"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="Page5.aspx" title="Page5"  description="Page5" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page6.aspx" title="Page6"  description="Page6" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page7.aspx" title="Page7"  description="Page7" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page8.aspx" title="Page8"  description="Page8" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page9.aspx" title="Page9"  description="Page9" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page10.aspx" title="Page10"  description="Page10" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page11.aspx" title="Page11"  description="Page11" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page12.aspx" title="Page12"  description="Page12" />
        <siteMapNode url="Page13.aspx" title="Page13"  description="Page13" />
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Also I have placed a sitemappath control on my aspx page-

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong. I read few articles and it says that this much of step is enough for adding breadcrumbs on every pages of a web site.
Please Guide me where I am doing Wrong?

Comment: What is the error...??

Comment: @MayankPathak I am getting a generic error.
I don't know what it is. Is the process in which I have proceeded is it correct or do you think I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually when I used menu control of asp.net in my sample project and tried the same approach, that time I was able to show the breadcrumbs. But in my actual project I am not using any menu control. I have made my menu using <a href=""></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SiteMapPath` control uses the `Web.sitemap` file by default. Also, place the sitemap file  in the root directory of the website and the URL attributes should be relative to the root directory.

Also the page you are trying to view must be included in the sitemap file else NO breadcrumb will show up on this page.

**EDIT::**

Make sure you include the `SiteMapPath` control on master page, so that it will be available for all your pages from `Page1.apsx` to `Page13.aspx` ( In case they all use a master file ), else you should place the SiteMapPath control individually on every page where you need to display the breadcrumb.

Also you mentioned your sitemap file as  `breadcrumb.sitemap`, just make sure it should be Web.sitemap. If it is already Web.sitemap, leave it.

Just tried your code and breadcrumb is displayed properly.[ Top left corner ]. In my case the SiteMapPath control was placed on master file.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have used web.sitemap file and I have also included my sitemap node with all the pages listed into it. I have posted the sample of my web.sitemap in my question. Still I am not able to implement breadcrumbs in my web pages. Please check the sample I have posted in my question. I am looking forward to your guidance sir.

Comment: Where have you placed your SiteMapPath control ?? should be on master file or on All pages individually. KIndly check the Edit made to my answer. Exactly copied your code and found this to be working with SiteMapPath placed on master file. It also works when placed the SiteMapPath indiviually on every page ( not a good practice)

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have placed sitemappath control in my master page outside the contentplaceholder. No actually I have three different master pages in my project, And I have made this breadcrumbs.sitemap file listing all the pages of my project. I have tried this sitemappath control with only one master page. Do I need to place sitemappath individually in every pages? Or Do I need to make three different .sitemap file for master pages? Listing respective pages?

Comment: YES, add the SiteMapPath control in every master file. Also, one thing really confusing still is that the name of your sitemap file is: Web.sitemap OR breadcrumb.sitemap ?? as you mentioned breadcrumb.sitemap in your above comment.It should be Web.sitemap.

Comment: Actually I have changed the name of the web.sitemap file to breadcrumbs.sitemap. So do I need to delete this file make a new file again?

Comment: No need to delete the file. Just rename it to Web.sitemap. Also place this file in root directory